# Как задать фиксированную высоту ячеек в первой колонке таблицы?

Tags: html, css, table

Во второй и третьей колонке может быть контента сколько угодно, а вот ячейки первой колонки нужны фиксированной высоты. Нужно использовать табличную верстку.
[скриншот](http://joxi.ru/BA06VwZie8dqmy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какие проблемы?

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  float: none;

}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;

}

.col-1 {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <div class="col-1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eleifend, sem quis viverra iaculis, elit ipsum pellentesque nunc, id sollicitudin ex dolor ac quam. Nullam sed mi eget massa viverra pellentesque. Mauris at urna sed dolor tempor mollis
      mattis in nunc. Aenean ultrices congue sapien et sollicitudin. Vivamus rhoncus, urna volutpat luctus pretium, diam metus tristique nunc, ac sagittis urna elit eget purus. Mauris dapibus, dui id vulputate finibus, nibh ipsum viverra elit, vel pharetra
      orci est id ligula. Quisque cursus tincidunt tristique. Aenean a pharetra sapien. Vivamus sagittis tellus ut risus finibus, ac aliquam metus volutpat. Morbi eleifend semper justo vitae rhoncus. Aliquam cursus dui sed tellus sagittis, vel ultrices
      erat ultrices. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell col-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eleifend, sem quis viverra iaculis, elit ipsum pellentesque nunc, id sollicitudin ex dolor ac quam. Nullam sed mi eget massa viverra pellentesque. Mauris at urna sed dolor tempor mollis
    mattis in nunc. Aenean ultrices congue sapien et sollicitudin. Vivamus rhoncus, urna volutpat luctus pretium, diam metus tristique nunc, ac sagittis urna elit eget purus. Mauris dapibus, dui id vulputate finibus, nibh ipsum viverra elit, vel pharetra
    orci est id ligula. Quisque cursus tincidunt tristique. Aenean a pharetra sapien. Vivamus sagittis tellus ut risus finibus, ac aliquam metus volutpat. Morbi eleifend semper justo vitae rhoncus. Aliquam cursus dui sed tellus sagittis, vel ultrices
    erat ultrices.</div>
  <div class="table-cell col-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eleifend, sem quis viverra iaculis, elit ipsum pellentesque nunc, id sollicitudin ex dolor ac quam. Nullam sed mi eget massa viverra pellentesque. Mauris at urna sed dolor tempor mollis
    mattis in nunc. Aenean ultrices congue sapien et sollicitudin. Vivamus rhoncus, urna volutpat luctus pretium, diam metus tristique nunc, ac sagittis urna elit eget purus. Mauris dapibus, dui id vulputate finibus, nibh ipsum viverra elit, vel pharetra
    orci est id ligula. Quisque cursus tincidunt tristique. Aenean a pharetra sapien. Vivamus sagittis tellus ut risus finibus, ac aliquam metus volutpat. Morbi eleifend semper justo vitae rhoncus. Aliquam cursus dui sed tellus sagittis, vel ultrices
    erat ultrices.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось намного проще, чем я думал. Нужно задать нужным ячейкам первой колонки display: block и высоту.
http://joxi.ru/DrlzjyeCaz8j2P